# Php's "new" WeakMap - do Enums ever get garbage collected?

Tags: php, weakmap

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.weakmap.php

what about Enums?

You can do

```
enum MyEnum{
case A;
}
```

```
$wm = new WeakMap();
$wm[MyEnum::A] = 'something';
```

when does

`$wm[MyEnum::A]` become invisible? or inaccessible? if ever?

I am NOT talking about `$wm`. Assume `$wm` is always there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An enum in php is just a (special) class with several constants, this is simple to verify:

```
enum MyEnum { case A; }

// enum(MyEnum::A)
// string(6) "object"
var_dump(  
    (new ReflectionClass(MyEnum::class))->getConstant('A'),
    gettype(MyEnum::A));
```

Because no one can unset a constant or change its value, there is at least one reference to the enum object, the entry in the WeakMap will remain until someone manually unsets it.